# What am I doing wrong in my Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery to create some Ajax request, the code apparently is working fine; but when I inspected the code with firebug, I see the request generate some unexpected **a** tags. The script is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some/request/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
        $('#main').html(data);

        // To see the error I do this:
        alert(data);
        alert($('#main').html());
    }
});
```

The alerts returns something like this:

**alert(data)->**

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**alert($('#main').html())->**

```
<div class="list">
    <a></a>
    <ul>
        <a></a>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The second return adds some extra tags **a**... I don't know why the method $('#main').html(data) is working in that way.

**EDIT- MORE INFORMATION:**

- I am using Firefox 7.01,  but in Google Chrome the same problems
  occurs.
- I am using jquery 1.6.2
- Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z4rYU/3/

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code you have there? It should work fine this way.

Comment: It seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/z4rYU/
Is your received `data` decoded/unquoted/etc properly? What is your browser/jquery/os version?

Comment: Hi, please see this http://jsfiddle.net/z4rYU/3/ it throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, your anchor tag is not closed properly. See corrected string below:

```
var data = '<div id="main-header"><ul id="breadcrumb"><li class="crumb"><a href="#/">option 1</a></li><li class="crumb"><a href="#/">option 2</a></li></ul>';

//Changed: <a href="#/">option 2<a>
//To:      <a href="#/">option 2</a>
```

Here's [a corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/gp5Ut/).

Comment: This was the problem! I reviewed my html code and I see that you are right... I was going crazy with this problem, thank you very much.

Comment: @edwines, You're welcome! BTW, welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest marking up both Rob and my answers and then selecting one of them as the correct answer.

Comment: I can't mark up because I only have 5 of rep... and again, thanks!